# import more than one unity3d projects to android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, plugins, android-library

I am able to export Unity3d android project and import it in android studio but how do i import more than one unity3d project in to android studio?
I tried importing it as a module but didn't work.

Every unity3d project dependent on unity-classes.jar file so when I import more than one projects it throws error

> Error:Execution failed for task :app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: 
>   Duplicate files copied in APK lib/armeabi-v7a/libmain.so

Answer (score 1):

Here how I solved this.

First you have to export unity and your scenes as android and check google development. Afterwards, you open any android project.

- 1.File ->new->import module ... and you select your unity project.
- 2.Open the gradle of your unity project (ex.build.gradle( Module:unity)) and you delete "apply plugin:..." and applicationId
  and instead you add at the top "apply plugin: 'com.android.library'"
- 3.You go to File->project structure and in modules you select your app.Then in dependencies, you press the + -> module dependency and
  you select your unity project.
- 4.In java UnityActivity you extend the activity as Fragment, and you add this code.

  ```
  public class UnityActivity extends Fragment {
      protected UnityPlayer mUnityPlayer; // don't change the name of this variable; referenced from native code
       private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
   public static UnityActivity newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
       UnityActivity fragment = new UnityActivity();
       Bundle args = new Bundle();
       args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
       fragment.setArguments(args);
       return fragment;
   }
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
       getActivity().getWindow().takeSurface(null);
       getActivity().setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
       getActivity().getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGB_565);
       mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(getActivity());
       if (mUnityPlayer.getSettings ().getBoolean ("hide_status_bar", true)) {
           getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                   WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
       }
       int glesMode = mUnityPlayer.getSettings().getInt("gles_mode", 1);
       boolean trueColor8888 = false;
       mUnityPlayer.init(glesMode, trueColor8888);
       mUnityPlayer.windowFocusChanged(true);
       mUnityPlayer.setX((float)-5);
       View playerView = mUnityPlayer.getView();
       return playerView;
   }
   // Quit Unity
   @Override public void onDestroy ()
   {
       mUnityPlayer.quit();
       super.onDestroy();
   }
   // Pause Unity
   @Override public void onPause()
   {
       super.onPause();
       mUnityPlayer.pause();
   }
   // Resume Unity
   @Override public void onResume()
   {
       super.onResume();
       mUnityPlayer.resume();
   }
   // This ensures the layout will be correct.
   @Override public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
   {
       super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
       mUnityPlayer.configurationChanged(newConfig);
   }
   // Notify Unity of the focus change.
   public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
   {
       super.getActivity().onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
       mUnityPlayer.windowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
   }
   // For some reason the multiple keyevent type is not supported by the ndk.
   // Force event injection by overriding dispatchKeyEvent().
   public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
   {
       if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_MULTIPLE)
           return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event);
       return super.getActivity().dispatchKeyEvent(event);
   }
   // Pass any events not handled by (unfocused) views straight to UnityPlayer
   public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)     { return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event); }
   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)   { return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event); }
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)          { return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event); }
   /*API12*/ public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event)  { return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event); }
      }
  ```

Comment: but the problem is for different Unity module *.so files having same name that will throws naming conflict when we are going to build project.

Answer (score -1):

I got exactly the same issue when I tried to import two Unity projects as two libraries to Android Studio. You have two solutions:

1. In the graddle.build of you app you add:

   ```
   android {
       ...

       packagingOptions {
           pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libmain.so'
           pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libmono.so'
           pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libunity.so'
           pickFirst 'lib/x86/libmain.so'
           pickFirst 'lib/x86/libmain.so'
           pickFirst 'lib/x86/libmain.so'
       }

       ...
   }
   ```
2. Or go to the project Window -> Android -> Under one of your Unity project locate the folder *jniLibs* and remove the folders *armeabi-v7* and *x86*.

Comment: this will not work as for different Unity module a *.so file architecture is different even if we use pickFirst or merge as packagingOptions it will pick only one .so file that will work only for one module.

Comment: how about dll file? your resource will be duplicate and apk is fat